# Count users according to custom meta_key tags

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, I created a custom user field called profession by ACF. It includes names of the professions for the subscriber to choose. I now want to count the number of users who selected each of those professions and print their number on screen. The custom meta key is stored in user_meta table.

How can I do that by using a PHP Snippet and inserting a shortcode on the page to show it?

I found and used the code below, but I get O.

I don't know php as you can see.

Thanks for the help

```
<?php
$args  = array(
    'meta_key' => 'profession',
    'meta_value' => 'Doktor'
);
$users= new WP_User_Query( $args );
echo $users->get_total();
?>
```

Comment: _"I found and used the code below, but I get O."_ - is your meta key _really_ called `proffession`, with a double `f` ...?

Comment: (This is going to be a highly inefficient way of doing this. This would really be one of those times were writing & executing a custom SQL statement would make a lot more sense.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php
    // Download user list
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

This code displays all users. You can call var_dump and check if it exists:

```
$user['meta_key'];
```

if so, just add conditions

```
if ($user['meta_key'] == 'Doctor') {
 ...
} else if ...
```